# Trying to return all matched values rather than just the first value from sheets results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am able to successfully return the value from the first or last position from a matched search in google sheets with the below code either using indexOf() or lastIndexOf(). Is there a way that it can return all positions and therefore all values of the search query rather than just one? I understand that indexOf() only returns 1 value. Essentially if the item is present more than once, the indexOf method returns the position of the first occurence rather than all of them.

The below code uses the value of the "model" field in my front-end form to find the position and return the price from the next column.

```
function getCost(model){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Index");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, 
  ws.getRange("B1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 
  ws.getRange("C1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()).getValues();

  var modelList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var priceList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  var dateList = data.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });

  var position = modelList.lastIndexOf(model);  

  var results = priceList[position];


  if(position > -1){
     return results;
  } else {
     return 'Please contact us for a valuation on this vehicle';
  }

}
```

This returns the price of the matched vehicle from the form but if there are multiple matches of the same vehicle model and different prices then I want to return all matched values rather than just one.

Also ideally I want to return all values and find the average price of the values returned. Is this also possible?

Thank you in advance, I am new to Javascript and Google Apps Script.

Comment: Have you considered the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method?

Comment: can't seem to get that to work @slim

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what data types these hold, but this should help you:

```
function getCost(searchedModel) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url)
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Index')
  const data = ws
    .getRange(
      1,
      1,
      ws
        .getRange('B1')
        .getDataRegion()
        .getLastRow(),
      ws
        .getRange('C1')
        .getDataRegion()
        .getLastRow()
    )
    .getValues()

  const results = data.filter(([model, price, date]) => searchedModel === model)

  if (results.length > 0) {
    return results
  } else {
    return 'Please contact us for a valuation on this vehicle'
  }
}
```

Comment: `const` and arrow functions are not available in Google Apps Script.

Comment: then rewrite the same code using var and function, or use babel... the point of the answer is not to give an exact working code, but show how to do it

Comment: This isn't my question, I was simply pointing out that the sample code won't work without tweaks in case OP was wondering why it wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks Mykybo and ross. I have tried the above code but can't get it working even with changing out 'const' with 'var'. I think it might be where you have put [model, price, data]. Where is it finding these positions?

Comment: have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment -- array desctructuring

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a solution that both returns all indexes, as well as calculates the average price:

```
function getCost(model){  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Index");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange("B1").getDataRegion().getLastRow(), ws.getRange("C1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()).getValues();
  var modelList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var priceList = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  var dateList = data.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });   
  var position=getAllIndexes(modelList, model); 
  var results = [];
  Logger.log(modelList);
  for(var j=0;j<position.length;j++){
    results.push(priceList[position[j]]);
  }
  Logger.log(results);
  if(results){
  var averageCost=average(results);
     return averageCost;
  } else {
     return 'Please contact us for a valuation on this vehicle';
  }
}

function getAllIndexes(modelList, model) {
  var indexes = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < modelList.length; i++){
        if (modelList[i] == model){
            indexes.push(i);
        }
      }
  Logger.log(indexes);
  return indexes;
}

function average(modelCost){
  var sum=0;
  for(var k=0;k<modelCost.length;k++){
    sum+=modelCost[k];
  }
  return (sum/modelCost.length);
}
```

I incorporated some logs in the code, so you can retrace better what each function is doing.

Please doublecheck if you range definition is as intended. The [syntax](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) is `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`.

Comment: This looks amazing! I am a bit of a novice however and am struggling to get the code to run. Might you be able to have a look at it on my apps script link? https://script.google.com/d/1os6FJfncePpDzBBl0GTJ4eKKX0sVMRwZpp0y3mq6lA55yAJVk1izzVsM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sure, but you need to give me permission

Comment: Did that link not give you permission? It should now

Comment: So what is your intention? You want to pass `averageCost` to function `updateEstimate`? Or `results`?

Comment: Great, I hope it all makes sense! I really appreciate this, i felt like I was getting so close but going around in circles

Comment: I want to be able to click the 'Value' button on the frontend which runs the updateEstimate function, but I need the result to be averageCost

Comment: I see.I did not realize you are deploying a WebApp, I modified my answer so it merges with the rest of your code.

Comment: Thanks, i feel like an idiot but I still can't get it to run the code... i must be reading it wrong

Comment: This code is an addition to the code you have already (including the doGet() function). You need to deploy your Web App as a new version after implementing changes.

Comment: I get this error - "ReferenceError: "arr" is not defined. (line 80, file "Code")"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not change all variable names when adapting the code from my version to your version. Try the version I just updated. I could not test my code snippet with your full script given that you provided me only viewing permissions.

Comment: I am still struggling, i dont know where its going wrong. I have updated permissions to edit, might you be able to check quickly for me? https://script.google.com/d/1os6FJfncePpDzBBl0GTJ4eKKX0sVMRwZpp0y3mq6lA55yAJVk1izzVsM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am trying to use this car '1960 Aston Martin DB4' as a test in as there should be 3 results/values

Comment: I see, your cell contents are currencies and not integer numbers, you need to manually change them to numbers and back in order to perform a calculation. Modify the average function to: `function average(modelCost){
  var sum=0;
  for(var k=0;k<modelCost.length;k++){
    sum+=parseInt(modelCost[k].substr(1));
    Logger.log(sum);
  }
  return ("£"+sum/modelCost.length+",000");
}
`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that in your code `var confirmation = document.getElementById("model").value = year + " " + make + " " + modely + " " + variant;` This means that if `variant` is left empty your search query will be  '1960 Aston Martin DB4 ' instead of  '1960 Aston Martin DB4' and thus will not be found in your sheet unless you delete the tailing space manually before submitting.